# How to check if select is going to block or not during run-time

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, operating-system, reverse-engineering, system-calls

Linux Man Page select command is as follows:

```
   int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
                  fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

It says

```
select()  and  pselect()  allow  a  program to monitor multiple file descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some
       class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible).  A file descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform a  corresponding  I/O  operation  (e.g.,
       read(2) without blocking, or a sufficiently small write(2)).
```

Also timeout returns from the select call when none of the descriptor is available within timelimit parameter unless it's 0 in which case it behaves as a blocking call.

I am debugging (instrumenting) a server by attaching an instrumentation like pintool to it. In this tool, I want to know whether my select call is going to block or not. Is there any way during the run time by looking at the memory, register or select arguments I can tell whether it's going to block or not.

PS. One thing which is coming in my mind is by using one more select call in the analysis routine before the actual select execution and passing the same argument values to the analysis routine select call and if select returns with 0 that means no descriptor is ready yet otherwise descriptor is ready. So by putting one more select before the actual select, I am trying to guess whether my actual select is going to block or not. Not sure - if this is the right way?

Comment: Well, any such determination would be stale by the time.it was returned.

Comment: No - let's assume clients are in my control who are actually making the descriptors ready for read, write or except in the select call

Comment: But during the runtime, I want to know at the server whether it's blocking because of no event ready? Before actually getting blocked by select

Comment: I don't see how you could reliably determine such a state when, between one machine instruction and the next, a network driver could have made a dozen fd ready for read/write.

Comment: True it's difficult to reliably know a state when server is blocking because no FD is ready. But I have a constraint that only one client will be connected to server at a time, my concern is to know the point in server side when this client has finished processing. And I could see when select blocks after server closed the client connection is the time when processing of that client's request is done.